# Testing if an url is valid or not to show/hide an image

Tags: xcode, swift

```
var TestYou = "www,aa.com" 
if let url = TestYou as? String {img.hidden = true}else{img.hidden = false}
```

I want to hide an image if an url is found. If it is not I want to show the image.

What do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: please use proper formatting for your code and describe what you are expecting to happen / what you've tried to fix your issue. Your question is unreadable like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I got that right from your "question" you are searching for something like this (do this in your `AppDelegate`):

```
    if let url = NSURL(string: ("www.aa.com")) {
        // check if your application can open the NSURL
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url){
            img.hidden = true //hide image
        } else {
            img.hidden = false //show image
        }
    }
```

Comment: for sample if i made var x = "wwww.gormaik.com" i just want do one command to check if there is url or empty like i add some url for video on image if i add the url for video then image will be hide if is there no urls for video then image will get show agin